# Enable Fn-Brightness Buttons Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, grub

I am trying to get the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> buttons to work on my `ASUS UX305F` laptop running `Ubuntu 14.04`. I have tried adding all of the following to `/etc/default/grub` without success:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

I have even tried mixing and matching some of them. Each time I ran `sudo update-grub` and restarted my computer only to be disappointed yet again. I also found that running `acpi_listen` produced no output when I pressed the keys leading me to believe that they are not captured. How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT:**

`acpi_listen` pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```
^[[15~
```

`acpi_listen` pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>:

No output

`xev` pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x9b, subw 0x0, time 41144271, (1,436), root:(783,488),
    state 0x0, keycode 71 (keysym 0xffc2, F5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x5000001,
    root 0x9b, subw 0x0, time 41144399, (1,436), root:(783,488),
    state 0x0, keycode 71 (keysym 0xffc2, F5), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

`xev` pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>:

No output

**EDIT 2:**

Bug filed here for reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1458351

Comment: What do you mean by `Fn+5` key? Do you mean you are pressing `Fn` key (which is alongside the `Alt` or `Ctrl` key) and the `5` numeric key? It will not send any special signal to your system. It will only send `5` to your system. `Fn` keys are hardware encoded. They don't work this way.

Comment: @shivams: You might post your comment as an answer. This is not the first time that the question of mapping Fn has come up, and it's always the same answer.

Comment: @harrymc Wonder why he has awarded a bounty for that. Anyways, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @shivams Please see edit

Comment: @cabellicar123 Okay i got that.

Comment: @cabellicar123 Open "Keyboard Shortcuts" in your Ubuntu and try assigning `Fn`+`F5` to some action in that list. See if you are able to assign there.

Comment: @shivams Tried it didn't recognize key press

Comment: @cabellicar123 Try using `xev` command also.

Comment: @cabellicar123 Also, using the `xev` command or `acpi_listen`  tell me when you press `F5` and `Fn`+`F5`, does it report detecting different codes or the same code. Moreover, when you press `Fn`+`F5`, does it even report anything in `xev`?

Comment: @shivams Please see edit. Both `acpi_listen` and `xev` do record things for Fn + other function keys

Comment: @cabellicar123 As per the output, it is clear that kernel is detecting it as different from `F5`. That is good. But why it is giving no output is strange. Anyways, did you try this : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

Comment: @shivams That was the default it came with

Comment: @shivams In case you are still interested I submitted an official bug testing with the latest kernel here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1458351

Comment: @cabellicar123 Oh. That's great. Let's see how they follow up on the bug report. By the way, we never asked your Asus laptop model number. Could you tell that (and include it in your question)? The problem so far appears to be related to your specific model.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find something?

Answer (score 6):

This is not how `Fn` keys work. If you press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>, it is not going to send any special signal to the system. It is only going to send `5` as the keystroke.

The thing to understand here is that <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys are hardcoded in your laptop keyboard. So, if you press <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with, let's say <kbd>F5</kbd> key, and if <kbd>F5</kbd> key has a small icon below it marked as mute, then it is going to send a special signal (which will mute your speakers, if everything is properly set).

If you combine your <kbd>Fn</kbd> key with any other key on the keyboard which have no special markings for <kbd>Fn</kbd> key, it is not going to send any special signal.

Comment: Fn+F10 (mute), Fn+F11 (vol down), Fn+F12 (vol up) all function correctly and have recorded signals in `acpi_listen` along with other function keys

Comment: In addition the F6 key and F7 key both have little icons and worked correctly with the Fn key when running windows

Comment: @cabellicar123: For most laptops, Fn+F10 etc. get translated *by the keyboard firmware* into a virtual-key code. You cannot map Fn, but you can map these virtual-key codes. Unfortunately, only some Fn combinations are handled by the keyboard firmware, and for the rest the result is undefined and most probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: @harrymc My question is why the keys worked then for windows. Wouldn't that indicate the keys were being mapped and that somehow Ubuntu isn't recognizing these codes?

Comment: You might add more information about what works on Windows that doesn't on Ubuntu. It might however be that Windows is relying less on the keyboard firmware than Ubuntu and so is using lower-level keyboard functions.

Comment: @harrymc All I really know is that brightness adjustments worked on windows when I was using it but having replaced it with Ubuntu they no longer work but other function keys do work

Answer (score 2):

Can you set your brightness without using keyboard shortcuts? If yes it's not a grub or acpi issue.

You actually need to set keybindings to brightness functions, common media keybindings are included by default, but in your case your brightness keybindings are not. Configure them by using Dconf Editor.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings

Comment: I can set brightness in system settings but shouldn't acpi log the events?

Comment: @cabellicar123: After Windows boots, the BIOS/UEFI is almost totally unused. Maybe that's the difference with Ubuntu.